# What is the purpose of constructor in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, parameters

1. Do constructors initialize attributes for a specific object at the time of object creation?

I created a simple class for addition.
I used constructor and initialized two parameters a and b.

Now I created an add method in that class. For which I used same letters a and b.

Now when I create an object, like

```
Object = class(a-value, b-value)
Print(object.add())
```

I was expecting that initialized a and b values to be sent to add method.
But error is still asking me to pass the positional arguments for add()

And when I `print(object.a)` - I get the initialized value for `a`!

So is constructor used for passing attributes for that specific object?

While `add` function needs parameters and arguments for those parameters?

Full Code(from comment):

```
class Addition:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def addition(self, a, b):
        add=a+b
        return add

object1 = Addition(20, 30)
print(object1.addition())
```

Comment: Can you share the exact code that is producing an error? I added code formatting but python is case sensitive and the code you provided would produce other errors.

Comment: Your "``object.add``" method will be passed the instance, not its attributes. For what you describe, ``add`` should *not* be expecting ``a`` and ``b`` but only ``self``.

Comment: Class Addition: (new line) def __init__(self, a, b): (new line) self.a = a & self.b =b (new line) def addition(self, a, b): (new line) add=a+b (new line) return add ( new line out of class indents) object1 = Addition(20, 30) (new line) print(object1.addition()) ......... End of code.! If I execute that I am getting error asking me to enter arguments for addition function. So those initialized a and b are attributes of object1 and have no relation to arguments of addition function???

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oooh! Why shouldnt it expect a and b in add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including local arguments when you don't need to.
Simply removing them and referring to the instance variables(attributes) will fix your problem.

```
class Addition:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def addition(self):
        add = self.a + self.b
        return add

object1 = Addition(20, 30)
print(object1.addition())
```

Python is very helpful when you create an object and implicitly passes the instance as the first argument to a bound method.

For this reason, we need to always include an argument in our methods that the instance can be handed to.

The standard name for this argument is `self` (although it can be anything) it is helpful to readers of your code to refer it to as everyone else does.

So calling `object1.addition()` is essentially doing this on a normal unbound function.

```
def normal_func_addition(some_object):
    add = some_object.a + some_object.b
    return add

object1 = Addition(20, 30)
print(normal_func_addition(object1))
```

Your other question was "Why need a constructor at all?"

The answer to this is it's a good place to set our attributes on the object.

Again, we could achieve this with a simple top level function.

```
def func_init(some_object, a, b):
    some_object.a = a
    some_object.b = b

class Addition:
    pass

object1 = Addition()
func_init(object1, 20, 30)
print(object1.a)
print(object1.b)
```

or even directly.

```
object1.a = 20
object1.b = 30
```

But that's a lot of boilerplate and it's nice to do it all in one step.

So in essence, `object1 = Addition(20, 30)` creates an `Addition` object (`object1`) and hands that object to `__init__` along with `20` and `30`.

There you assign the attributes `.a` and `.b` to it. Then when you call `object1.addition()` it again hands the instance (`object1`) to it. There you can pull the attributes back out that you assigned in `__init__`.

Comment: Oooh! So.. addition(self) is saying, go to the object in this instance and get whatever variables/attributes that are initialized and use them as arguments for addition function! Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. There's nothing saying the attributes need to be added in `__init__`. You could add them elsewhere. It's just a good place to do it.

Comment: Yeap got it! And yes we can add attributes after creating object like, object.a = 10. Instead of using constructors. Thanks a bunch for the answer :))

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b


test = Test(15, 10)
print(test.a)
print(test.b)

print(test.add())
```

Comment: Yup this was helpful!! I added parameters a & b in add function too, reason why error asks me for arguments. I dont understand why add function only requires self. Maybe there is more to know about "self" ?

Comment: The task of constructors is to initialize(assign values) to the data members of the class when an object of class is created.

Comment: Ok. But then why there is no need to parameters a and b in add function? Why just "self" is sufficient?

Comment: "Self" is always pointing to Current Object. "Self" represents the instance of the class

Comment: Yeeah!! So its saying go to the object, check if any values are initialized and use them as arguments. Hence the simple add(self) in your code. If we dont wanna use those values that are initialized we can pass custom arguments to add() right?